# Raspbian file manager right click menu

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch

Alright, so I'm looking to add an element to the right-click menu, in Raspbian's file menu.  When you right-click in "negative space" in the FM, you get a litany of options:

- Create New >
- Paste
- Select All
- Invert Selection
- Sort Files >
- Show Hidden

I'm looking to add an element to this list.  I need it to run a custom program for someone who isn't computer literate.

I can configure the OpenBox options in `~/.config/openbox/lx...`, but I'm having a difficult time finding where these options are located.

Does anybody know where I can add elements to this menu?

Answer (score 1):

Two-and-a-half years later...

I was able to accomplish this using the `nautilus-actions-config-tool`. I know Raspian / Raspberry Pi OS don't actually run nautilus, but [LXDE](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/PCManFM#Add_own_options_to_the_files_context_menu) (and others) supports the same "[Desktop Entry Specification](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/)", and rather than edit .desktop files myself, I used the nautilus tool and it worked okay. (Note: I had to do a full reboot to get it to pick up changes. `lxpanelctl restart && openbox --restart` wasn't working for me.)

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
nautilus-actions-config-tool
```

Good luck; have fun!